# iOS: abrir pdf do webview no browser OU fazer download do pdf

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview, download

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo para iOS com Swift. Ele funciona perfeitamente, porém quando clico no link de download do pdf, ele apenas exibe o pdf. Eu queria que ele fizesse o downdload OU abrisse o pdf no browser fora do webview. Quem tiver alguma solução ficarei grato, pois já estou um tempo tentando resolver isso. Em algumas pesquisas vi um pessoal comentando sobre configarar o Delegate, mas como é essa configuração? Há necessidade dela ser feita ?

```js
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak
  var myWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let url = URL(string: "http://site/")
      let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
      myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
 

 //Eu tentei fazer isso, mas ele abre o pdf no browser quando abro o aplicativo, sendo que a ideia é abrir o pdf só qnd eu clicar no link. Um link que gera um boleto 

if let url = URL(string: "https://prod-bepay-boletos.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/boleto-A96C9542-79F4-9A8F-E2F1-F26120DABC45.pdf") {
  UIApplication.shared.open(url)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que voce precisa na verdade é monitorar a navegação do usuário. Voce pode fazer isso no UIWebView também mas o UIWebView ta **deprecated** então eu recomendo usar o WKWebView pra isso:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Documents\n", FileManager.documents)
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}

extension FileManager {
    static let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
}
```

---

E implemente o metodo `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` pra detectar quando o usuario clica num link e se esse link é um pdf:

```
extension ViewController {
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
                url.pathExtension == "pdf" {
                print("pdf url:\n", url, "\nNo need to open locally")
                decisionHandler(.cancel)

                // se voce quiser pode download o pdf
                URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
                    guard let location = location, let response = response else {
                        print("error:", error ?? "nil")
                        return
                    }
                    print("Location:", location.path, "\nResponse:", response, "\nFilename:", response.suggestedFilename ?? "file.pdf")
                    do {
                        let destination = FileManager.documents.appendingPathComponent(response.suggestedFilename ?? "file.pdf")
                        print("destination:", destination.path)
                        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location,  to: destination)
                        print("file moved from temporary location to documents directory")
                    } catch {
                        print("File copy/move error:", error)
                    }
                }.resume()
                // ou exibir usando o safari
                // if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                //    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                //     print(url)
                //    print("abrindo pdf com default browser")
                // }
                //
            } else {
                print("user clicked on a link that it is not a pdf")
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo, @Leo esse método func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: aescaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void). É o que vai na delegate.swift ?

Comment: Pode colocar em qualquer arquivo dentro do seu projeto. Pode colocar também no mesmo do ViewControler embaixo de tudo. Também pode tirar da extensão e colocar direto dentro do seu view controller

Comment: tá apresentando esse erro: " WKWebView before iOS 11.0 (NSCoding support was broken in previous versions) " .Ou seja eu estou trabalhando com a versão 10 e parece que nao suporta versão inferior à 11.

Comment: Tenho certeza que esse erro não e do meu código iOS10 suporta WKWebView com certeza. Nem estou usando NSCoding. Não tenho como resolver o seu problema sem ver o seu código. Pra que voce precisa que o seu ViewController inherit from NSCoding?

Comment: Também achei estranho, vou dar um olhada na minha "Main.storyboard" o problema tá lá. Mas em relação ao seu código, tá tudo certinho mesmo, só importei o Webkit, tá zerado, sem nenhum erro.

Comment: resolvido cara! Obrigado. Só não sei o porque ele está dando zoom no aplicativo.

Comment: De nada, boa sorte :)

Comment: Voce pode usar um customUserAgent no seu WKWebView usando o user agent do Safari pro mac e fazer ele mostar a versão desktop do site

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma procurada aqui. Mais uma vez, obrigado ! :)

Comment: tá complicado tirar esse efeito "pinch zoom". Eu tentei o seguinte..:
 func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIWebViewNavigationType?) {
  scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
 }  Não rolou... Tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer esse esquema que vc disse?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31943976/2303865

Comment: É esse aí foi o primeiro que tentei, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai um esboço de solução para o seu problema. 
O método *downloadPDF* faz o download do arquivo e salva no dispositivo, usando a classe *FileDownloader*. O PDF será salvo dentro da pasta *Documents*.

O método *displayPDF* utiliza *UIDocumentInteractionController*
para encontrar aplicativos aptos a mostrar o arquivo.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    func pdfFileURL() -> URL {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let pdfFileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("file.pdf")
        return pdfFileURL
    }

    func downloadPDF() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.server.com/file.pdf")
        FileDownloader.load(url: url!, to: self.pdfFileURL(), completion: { (success) in
            print("Download succeeded? \(success)")
        })
    }

    func displayPDF() {
        let fileURL = self.pdfFileURL()
        if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path)) {
            print("File not found")
            return
        }
        let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: fileURL)
        documentController.delegate = self
        documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }

    //MARK: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}

class FileDownloader {
    class func load(url: URL, to destination: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in

            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading file: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            if let urlResponse = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse, urlResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if let localURL = localURL {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localURL, to: destination)
                        completion(true)
                        return
                    } catch (let writeError) {
                        print("Error writing file to \(destination) : \(writeError)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Server returned an error")
            }

            completion(false)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```